# See caller info without unlocking on Moto G 2nd gen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g2

In my Moto G 2nd gen, when a call arrives I can hear the ringtone, but the screen is black. I can't see who's calling. In order to see that I had to unlock my mobile. Is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, it's because you have received an update of Lollipop 5.0.2.

To resolve this issue, go to **Settings** and change the priority of the "Phone" app to high priority, then go to **Notification**, and change way of notifying to "Interrupt for anything"